# PHP Startup: unable to load dynamic library 'C:\xampp\php\ext\php_memcached.dll' -%1 is not a valid Win32 application

Tags: memcached

> PHP Startup: unable to load dynamic library
>   'C:\xampp\php\ext\php_memcached.dll' -%1 is not a valid Win32
>   application.

This error is keep showing whenever I restart Apache Server(Using xampp).
I have installed `memcached` and started using command prompt, `memcached.exe -d` start and its running fine as I checked task manager.

Now, How to fix it? Am I not using right .dll file?

Comment: Hello and wlcome to Stackoverflow    -- follow this tutorial : http://stannesi.blogspot.fr/2011/11/how-to-install-memcache-on-xampp.html i fixed similar problem

Answer (score 4):

Try phpinfo() and check right on top, where it says Compiler, if you downloaded the correct VC8/9/10 32/64bit version of the .dll, exchange it - if needed - restart apache and you should be fine. Sometimes this can be a bit tedious to find the corresponding .dll's, good luck!

Comment: I am having same issue of php_memcache.ddl. With VC8/9/10 32/64bit version of the .dll, I didn't get your mean by VC8/9/10 32/64bit. When I tried `phpinfo()`, the Compiler value is `Visual C++ 2017` and the `php version` is `7.4.14`. Can you please guide what should I do to get it fixed.

Answer (score 0):

yes. regardless windows 64, 86 version nor non-thread safe version or other. Try all version to figure out if what version is suite for your xampp.